# Why we need to pass "$event" in ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I know we can perform click events like `ng-click="clickMe()"` in angular.But I just gone through some examples.In that `$event` is passed into that like this `ng-click="clickMe()"` .
Why we need to pass `$event`?
What is the difference between `ng-click="clickMe()"` and `ng-click="clickMe($event)"` ?
Please anyone explain.

Comment: One passes the click event to the method, one doesn't. If you need the event, you pass it. If you don't, you don't pass it.

Comment: What is the difference between `ng-click="clickMe()"` and `ng-click="clickMe()"` ? They look identical to me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to, and most of the time you shouldn't. From all clicks in javascript, there is an `Event`-object available. $event just happens to be the way to access those in javascript.

If you are interested in more about the events, try this (not really related but good to know), if you are using chrome dev-tools, check the **Sources**-tab and on the right side you have watches and breakpoints. There is also a drop down for "**Event Listener Breakpoints**".  There you'll find a whole lot of possible events.

Try checking the checkbox for "**Mouse**" -> "**click**" for example, and then click somewhere on the page.  The script will pause (very likely somewhere in jquery) and you can inspect the mouseevent directly under the **Scope** dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

`$event`

> Directives like ngClick and ngFocus expose a $event object
>   within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a
>   [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.

with this object you have various properties and functions that can help you to manage event handling.

for example:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.